# Combining Android RelativeLayout with Gone Views

Tags: android, android-layout, optimization, android-relativelayout

Is there a good way to combine RelativeLayout with Views that might be gone?

For example if I wanna have a row with four buttons, and the two in the middle might become visibility="gone" during some runtime cases.

I can't use android:layout_below because then they will not be neatly arranged instead they will overlap each other. I guess I could programmatically change which view is below which one, but that seems very messy.

Right now I usually end up adding a LinearLayout, but I wonder if there is any good way to achieve this without adding an extra layout.

Comment: have you tried toRightOf="@id/yourButtonId" or toLeftOf="@id/yourButtonId" in your buttons

Comment: I need to have them from Top to Bottom, how would I use Right/Left for that?

Comment: You said row which implies horizontal alignment... I see you said "below which one" which I missed. Maybe it would help everyone if you posted some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this flag

```
android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
```

take a look at the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing)